# savedInstanceState is null when onCreateView is called in Fragment even though I overrided onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments

I added up button to tool bar to navigate from fragment B to fragment A.

When I click up button, I couldn't restore the member variables of A fragment

Because savedInstanceState was null even though I Overrided

onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and put all the variables which I wanted to restore later.

I did my best to search the reason, but I couldn't find the reason and the solutoin.

There were differeces between my situation and questions(answers) of other posts.

First, my fragment is hosted dynamically, so I couldn't give an id to my fragment in XML or something.

Second, it works when I rotate my device(savedInstanceState is not null on onCreateView()). I thought both(to rotate the device and to navigate from fragment B to fragment A) is the same situation

in that the fragment A is destroyed and recreated so onSaveInstanceState method

is called first and onCreateView is called after fragment A is recreated.

I have no idea why such situation occured. Please help me. Thanks.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mSubtitleVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE);
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);
    mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
    mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    updateUI();
    return view;
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE, mSubtitleVisible);
}
```

the full code of Fragment B

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by sgc109 on 2017-10-05.
 */

public class CrimeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_CRIME_ID = "crime_id";
    private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "DialogDate";
    private static final String DIALOG_TIME = "DialogTime";
    private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_TIME = 1;

    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private Button mTimeButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

    public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID, crimeId);

        CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UUID crimeId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_CRIME_ID);
        mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mCrime.setTitle(s.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
                dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
                dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
            }
        });
        mTimeButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_time);
        mTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                TimePickerFragment dialog = TimePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
                dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_TIME);
                dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_TIME);
            }
        });

        updateDateAndTimeButton();

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
        mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_DATE){
            Date date = (Date)intent.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
            mCrime.setDate(updateDate(date));
            updateDateAndTimeButton();
        }
        else if(requestCode == REQUEST_TIME){
            Date date = (Date)intent.getSerializableExtra(TimePickerFragment.EXTRA_TIME);
            mCrime.setDate(updateTime(date));
            updateDateAndTimeButton();
        }
    }

    private Date updateDate(Date date){
        Calendar calOld = Calendar.getInstance();
        calOld.setTime(mCrime.getDate());
        Calendar calNew = Calendar.getInstance();
        calNew.setTime(date);

        calNew.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calOld.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        calNew.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calOld.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        return calNew.getTime();
    }

    private Date updateTime(Date date){
        Calendar calOld = Calendar.getInstance();
        calOld.setTime(mCrime.getDate());
        Calendar calNew = Calendar.getInstance();
        calNew.setTime(date);

        calNew.set(Calendar.YEAR, calOld.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calNew.set(Calendar.MONTH, calOld.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calNew.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calOld.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        return calNew.getTime();
    }

    private void updateDateAndTimeButton() {
        mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDateString());
        mTimeButton.setText(mCrime.getTimeString());
    }

    public void returnResult(){
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you're using to show Fragment B as well as the code you're using to go "up" to Fragment A?

Comment: @BenP. I added as you asked

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that launches Fragment A or B

Comment: I don't launch Fragment A from B. Fragment A creates an Activity which hosts Fragment B and I just go back clicking up button. I just navigated.

Comment: Do your `onSaveInstanceState()` implementations in Fragment A and Activity A both call `super`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `Activity` created after `onCreateView` .

You can use `onActivityCreated` method to restore the fragment's state here .

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSubtitleVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE);
    }
    Log.e("TAG", "onActivityCreated OK");
    Log.e("TAG", savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE) + "");
}
```

**Edit**

Change to `onViewStateRestored` method,and try again .

Add log in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onViewStateRestored` ,make sure all of them work .

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSubtitleVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE);
    }
    Log.e("TAG", "onActivityCreated OK");
    Log.e("TAG", "onActivityCreated " + savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE));
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE, mSubtitleVisible);
    Log.e("TAG", "onSaveInstanceState OK");
    Log.e("TAG", "onSaveInstanceState" + mSubtitleVisible);
}
```

**Edit**

You can save the status in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onDestroyView`.

Then,restore the state in `onActivityCreated`

You can do like this.

```
Bundle savedState;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore State Here
    if (!restoreStateFromArguments()) {
        // First Time, Initialize something here
        onFirstTimeLaunched();
    }
}

protected void onFirstTimeLaunched() {
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Save State Here
    saveStateToArguments();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    // Save State Here
    saveStateToArguments();
}

private void saveStateToArguments() {
    if (getView() != null)
        savedState = saveState();
    if (savedState != null) {
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        b.putBundle("savedState", savedState);
    }
}

private boolean restoreStateFromArguments() {
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    savedState = b.getBundle("savedState");
    if (savedState != null) {
        restoreState();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Restore Instance State Here
private void restoreState() {
    if (savedState != null) {
        // For Example
        uSelected.setText(savedState.getString("uSelected"));
        onRestoreState(savedState);
    }
}

protected void onRestoreState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

// Save Instance State Here
private Bundle saveState() {
    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    // For Example
    state.putString("uSelected", uSelected.getText().toString());
    onSaveState(state);
    return state;
}

protected void onSaveState(Bundle outState) {
}
```

**Fragment life cycle**

[image]

Comment: And remove `if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mSubtitleVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_SUBTITLE_VISIBLE);
    }` from `onCreateView`

Comment: Wow, It works! Thank you so much!!
Can I ask you why there is the difference between to remove that code from onCreateView and not to?

Comment: And I didn't understand 'Becuase the Activity created after onCreateView' actually. Would you mind explaining me more detail?

Comment: Because the Activity created after `onCreateView` .And ·Fragment· attached to `Activity` .So we can get data in `onActivityCreated` method .

Comment: You can look at the lift cycle of `Fragment` .You can know it .

Comment: I did. Btw, I have one more question.
Can I get saved date from savedInstanceState onlye once?
why the problem occurred when I use 'getBoolean()' after I used once in 'onCreateView()' ?

Comment: I did not know .I always use `savedInstanceState` in `onActivityCreated` .Sorry.Good luck to you .

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry KeLiuyue, but suddnly It doesn't work..... I have no idea why It worked well right before and not now.

Comment: You can clean you project and build it .

Comment: Could you do something about it?

Comment: Sure. What should I do?

Comment: I edited it .You can check all of your method work in your code .

Comment: When I press the button which launches an activity which hosts fragment B,
I can see a log 'onSaveInstanceState OK'. And then when I press navigation button and go back to fragment A, I can see a log 'onViewStateRestored OK'. But variable is not restored.

Comment: You can try again and see the log info .

Comment: It doesn't even run. I debuged and I found savedInstanceState is null when it calls getBoolean().

Comment: I was wrong. It runs, but runtime error occurs. And I told you the reason above.

Comment: I edited it .The whole method I use before is ok .You can try it.

Comment: I'm just wondering why I have to do this if I want to save member variable of the fragment? just curious. Why it doesn't use 'outState' and make new Bundle and call putBundle?

Comment: Oh, you did not do this .

Comment: I thought I could imagine Approximate result because I could read the code.
But I just asked you before I do that